# php.ini open_basedir has a master value of no value, but a local value

Tags: php

I have changed php.ini and set open_basedir to no value. However, in phpinfo(), there is a local value. I'm using a script that requires open_basedir to be no value to install. How can I remove the local value? I'm on a vps. I have also tried using .htaccess to set it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by editing httpd.conf which has set the open_basedir. I simply removed the php admin directives in httpd.conf and the local value became null.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `ini_set('open_basedir', NULL);` in a file the install script will be including such as the `index.php` file or a config file.

It may be that you don't have access to override configuration variables per folder (either with php.ini, .htaccess or ini_set).

To check if this is the case (since it's a VPS) look into `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and check if [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) is set to none.

This may also be the case for your specific vhost not necessarily for your default vhost configuration.